# How to change value of cookie via socket.io?

Tags: javascript, sockets, express, cookies, socket.io

I need to answer the question as the title. How to change value of cookie via socket.io?

Below is my entire code:

```
const path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var cookieIoParser = require('socket.io-cookie');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

 app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')))
 app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'js')))

 app.use(cookieParser())
 io.use(cookieIoParser)

 /*
  * Access-Control-Allow to /fb-dialog
  */

 app.get('/fb-dialog', function (req, res, next) {

  var wildcard = true;
  var credentials = true;

  var Origin = (wildcard && !credentials || !req.headers.origin ? '*' : req.headers.origin);

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', Origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,X-Requested-With,content-type');

    if(credentials){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    }

    next();

 })


 app.get('/fb-dialog', function(req, res){

   var cookies = cookieParser.JSONCookies(req.cookies);

   if(!cookies.fbdialog){
   res.cookie('fbdialog', 'true')
   }

  if(req.headers.origin){

    res.send('<html>...</html>'); // Here is creating a html

  }

 });


 /*
  * Socket.io
  */

 io.on('connection', function(socket){

 console.log('a user connected: ' + socket.id);

   socket.on('card-heading', function(){

   var cookies = socket.request.headers.cookie;

   if(cookies.fbdialog){
     socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=false');
     console.log('false: ' + cookies.fbdialog);
   }else{
     socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=true');
     console.log('true: ' + cookies.fbdialog);
   }
   });

   socket.on('typing', function(){
   socket.broadcast.emit('typing');
   });

   socket.on('clear', function(){
   socket.broadcast.emit('clear');
   });

   socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
   console.log('the user wrote:' +msg);
   socket.broadcast.emit('chat message', msg);
   });

 });

 http.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This my entire code. I used your example in if block but as I said I always getting socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=true');

Comment: Unfortunately `socket.io-cookie` does not work for me. I used `socket.io-cookie-parser` and it works nice. I will update my code..

Comment: When I use cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie); while I'm calling socket.on('card-heading', function(){ ... } my app is crash and return error log with: ReferenceError: cookie is not defined

Comment: When you use `cookie.parse` you need to define `const cookie = require('cookie');` and run `npm install cookie` first.

Comment: I updated my code to use `cookieIoParser` with the module `socket.io-cookie-parser`. Please have a look at it

Comment: I think I know what's going on. I thought that socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=false'); is creating a cookie on the user side. I check my preference in Firefox and value of my cookie all the time is true. I say myself, what is wrong? And socket.emit only emits and I must use socket.on in my javascript. I don't have socket.on so it can't work for me. I understand that node.js can only check value of cookie but he don't creating a cookie on your side?

Comment: Yes, exactly! You have to create `document.cookie` in your website javascript. Look at my example in `cookie.html` file.

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution (UPDATED):

cookie.js:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const cookieIoParser = require('socket.io-cookie-parser');
var cookies;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/cookie.html');
});

io.use(cookieIoParser());

io.on('connect', function(socket){
  cookies = socket.request.cookies;
  console.log(cookies);
  if(cookies.fbdialog){
    socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=false');
  } else {
    socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=true');
  }
});

http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

cookie.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sending cookies with socket.io</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id='socket'>not connected</h1>
    <h3 id='username'></h3>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();       
      socket.on('connect', function(){
        document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML = 'connected to the server';
      });      
      socket.on('cookie', function(cookie) {
        document.cookie = cookie;
        document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = 'cookies: ' + document.cookie;
      });
      socket.on('disconnected',function(){
        document.getElementById('socket').innerHTML = 'disconnected';
      });        
    </script>
  </body>  
</html>
```

1. Run `npm install socket.io-cookie-parser --save`,
2. Start server with `node cookie` and go to `localhost:3001` with your browser.
3. Please remember that the whole operation of setting cookies happens in the client `cookie.html` with `socket.on('cookie'...)` code.

Comment: Is there a better solution? If I can get value of cookie in this way: socket.request.headers.cookie; after socket connection, maybe it can set a value?

Comment: You can read cookies from `socket.request.headers.cookie` but it is the socket object property which is set at the moment of `connect` and will not update after you add/change your cookie. You can parse `socket.request.headers.cookie` to check what cookies are set but you can't  set cookies with it.

Comment: Btw, `socket.request.headers.cookie` is of type `string` so `cookies.fbdialog` will not work, you have to parse it first.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the server:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const cookie = require('cookie');
var cookies;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/cookie.html');
});

io.on('connect', function(socket){
  cookies = cookie.parse(socket.request.headers.cookie);
  if(cookies.fbdialog){
    socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=false');
  } else {
    socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=true');  
  }
});

http.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

I hope it now works as you wanted.

Comment: I added at the beginning io.use(cookieIoParser) so cookies in socket are parsed. Your example look good but unfortunately it not works. I see that socket.emit('cookie', 'fbdialog=true'); is like transparent. This function not working even as I will immediately after the connection.

Comment: My example works fine for me. I use `cookie` package which comes with express by default to parse `socket.request.headers.cookie`. I guess you use `var cookieIoParser=require('socket.io-cookie-parser');` - if yes then your parsed cookies are in `socket.request.cookies` - try it.

Comment: I don't understand. I prescribe your code and on my side it's not works. In my case in if block a cookie never exists although in de fact are exists. I update my code.

Comment: What is your `cookieIoParser` ? Do you have a line like `var cookieIoParser = require('...some module here... ');` ? Please show me